# AWS RDS MYSQL Optimization For Writes (INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE)

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have a rds t3.small instance which we perform write actions on. We have 2 read replicas for this instance which we route to using weighted routing policy via Route53. The reads are fine for now but we are getting massive operations for the write (master) database instance. CPU Utilization is nearing baseline of 20% and connections keep increasing (we are using connection pools but the traffic is too much)

Any possibilities on how we can manage load for writes? Is it possible to launch another instance for the same rds mysql database?

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions for your t3.small instance improvements.

Comment: What are the "writes"?  Do you have `DELETEs` or `UPDATEs` that hit more than a few rows?  Do you `INSERT` only one row at a time (versus 'batching' in some way)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't distribute writes across multiple instances, they all have to go to the master instance. It sounds like you will soon need to increase the size of the writer instance. If downtime is a concern, you could add a new, larger instance as a read replica, and then promote it as the new writer instance.

Answer (score 1):

All RDS instance types suck for write performance. They all use remotely-attached EBS storage, and remote storage incurs a heavy performance penalty for I/O.

At my last job, I benchmarked RDS versus Aurora for MySQL, and also benchmarked our physical servers (non-cloud) and also tested MySQL installed manually on EC2 `i3` instances. RDS had consistent poor performance by a wide margin.

The `t3` instances will be even worse, because they use burstable performance. Their baseline performance assumes a very light load, and they can add a burst of extra performance but only for short periods.

If you have write performance issues, especially for an application that requires consistent high performance, then you should upgrade to a more powerful instance type such as `M5` or `R5`.

I would move away from RDS. I think it's useful only for very light load, or for temporary use during testing or development. I would recommend using Aurora instead of RDS, but my first preference would be to operate MySQL myself on EC2 `i3` instances.

Comment: however large your instance type, if you don't pay for enough provisioned IOPS, it's going to suck.  Isn't running it yourself on EC2 also going to use EBS?  I only have experience with mariadb on rds

Comment: `i3` instances have direct-attached NVMe storage. Using these, I was able to get benchmark results that matched our on-premise servers. But it's instance storage, so you need to run replicas and have a failover solution to prevent data loss.

Comment: In my benchmarking experience, paying for provisioned IOPs on EBS is a waste of money. Just use general-purpose gp2 EBS volumes. If that's not fast enough, then you need to change your usage of the database (i.e. caching or sharding). Paying for IOPs is not going to save you from bad architecture, it's just going to give AWS lots of money.